# Gorm preload gives ambiguous column error

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have following structs

```
type Employee struct {
    EmployeeID        int64  `gorm:"primary_key;column:employee_id"`
    EmployeeCode      string `gorm:"column:employee_code"`
    FirstName         string `gorm:"column:first_name"`
    LastName          string `gorm:"column:last_name"`
    DesignationID     int64  `gorm:"column:designation_id;"`
    Designation       *Designation `gorm:"foreignkey:DesignationID"`
}

type Designation struct {
    DesignationID   int64  `gorm:"primary_key;column:designation_id"`
    DesignationName string `gorm:"column:designation_name"`
}

func GetEmployee(id int64) (*Employee, error) {
    db := connection.GetConn() //get connection
    defer db.Close()

    employee := &Employee{}
    err := db.Model(employees).Preload("Designation", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return db.Join("INNER JOIN employees ON employees.designation_id = designations.id").Order("employees.first_name DESC")
    }).Find(employee).Error
    return employee, err
}
```

The query that gets generated is

```
SELECT * FROM employees;
SELECT * FROM designations INNER JOIN employees ON employees.designation_id = designations.id WHERE id IN (1,2) order by employees.first_name DESC;
```

I have a join which is similar to what I have written in above function. Here I am not able to justfiy the join but in actual case I know that join is required and the preloading table and the join table both have `id` field in them.
Since both tables have same column name i.e. `id` in that case MYSQL throws error saying

`Error 1052: Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous`

I am facing this issue in **gorm v1.9.16**

I have not found any resource where similar issue is mentioned.
How do we solve this issue?

Comment: Which version of gorm are you using?

Comment: I am currently using gorm v1

Comment: https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/2653

Which one exactly v1.x.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try with a recent version (> v1.20.x)?

The issue has been closed https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/2653

The issue seems to be fixed in the new version https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/commit/2ae0653af2bc19cd31f687e797b189c85f0ac3f6

Comment: Thanks Stéphane. I will try it with the newer version.